# Don't understand ComboBox text rendering

Tags: c#, gtk

I'm trying write c# app with Gtk, which can load classes by reflection and view all method on the form. I added a ComboBox component to display and choose classes that available for choose. But when I fill combo box items, they render incorrectly as you can see on [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBbzj.png)

The  titles are repeating as much as I have items in combobox (if count of items is 4 then it will be 4 repeats)

To fill combo box, I did next:

```
            ListStore model = new ListStore(typeof(string), typeof(Type));
            

            foreach (var type in allImplementsOf)
            {
                var iter = model.AppendValues(type.Name, type);
                CellRendererText c = new CellRendererText();
                _classComboBox.PackStart(c, true);
                _classComboBox.AddAttribute(c, "text", 0);
            }
            
            _classComboBox.Model = model;
```

How can I fix it?
P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CellRenderer` works on the layer of the `ComboBox`, not on the level of a single entry. Thus, your `ComboBox` needs a single renderer which can render each entry. The reason for each entry text being rendered `n` times is that you use `n` renderers where each one is applied for each single entry. It should work if you just move the renderer out of the loop:

```
ListStore model = new ListStore(typeof(string), typeof(Type));
        

foreach (var type in allImplementsOf)
{
    var iter = model.AppendValues(type.Name, type);
            
}
        
_classComboBox.Model = model;
CellRendererText c = new CellRendererText();
_classComboBox.PackStart(c, true);
_classComboBox.AddAttribute(c, "text", 0);
```